# Reuse a Spring-boot submodule in another non Spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm working on a multi module spring-boot project to build a REST API. Here is my project structure:

- Parent project (packaging is pom)

  - core module (@SpringBootApplication + handle path like / or /status)
  - restControllerA module (Handle path like /routeA/*)
  - restControllerB module (Handle path like /routeB/*)

Everything is working in this project :)

In another non Spring project I would like to reuse a service of restControllerB. This service return the result of the request body validation.
First I try to add the restControllerB.jar as a dependency to this new project... But this jar does not contain its depedencies (who are in the fatJAR "core.jar"). When I run the project, I get a lot of ClassNotFoundException.

How can I manage to reuse this service as a dependency ? I thought to create a validator module which implements the validatorService interface, but I'm not sure if it is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours googling, It seems that creating an external librairy is the right choice. I create an external module and add it as a dependecy to restControllerB.